# Numeric UpDown in c#

Tags: c#, numeric

i'm fairly new to c#.

All i want to do is that if the numeric up down's value is for say greater than 4.6 but smaller than 6.0 to change its back color to green, if its out of the range then change it to red.

But i cannot seem to do this!

I have already tried declaring a float, converting the numeric value to float but still no luck!

Thanks

Comment: are you able to share some code that you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can just cast it to a double first and it will work.

Example:

```
if ((double)numericUpDown1.Value > 4.6 && (double)numericUpDown1.Value < 6.0)
{
    numericUpDown1.BackColor = Color.Green;
}
else
{
    numericUpDown1.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

When you are doing comparisons like that you just have to make sure that the data on both sides are of the same datatype.  Since a NumericUpDown value is decimal, the number you are comparing it to has to also be a decimal, or you have to convert it to what you are trying to compare.  So the other way you could say the same thing is this:

```
if (numericUpDown1.Value > 4.6m && numericUpDown1.Value < 6.0m)
{
    numericUpDown1.BackColor = Color.Green;
}
else
{
    numericUpDown1.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

In this second case the m tells visual studio that it is a decimal.